# Adding SpecialAccount to QuickBooks using SpcialAccountAdd xml request

Tags: c#, quickbooks

Is anybody know how to add specialaccount to QucikBooks using SpecialAccountAdd xml request and how to view the same in QuickBooks UI. I am using QuickBooks14.0 Enterprise Trail Edition.

Thanks and Regards
Venkatesan

Answer (score 0):

The OSR should give you all the needed information on how to create the XML request. You can access the OSR here https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html . Based on the OSR, here is what a request would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
  <SpecialAccountAddRq>
    <SpecialAccountAdd> <!-- required -->
      <!-- SpecialAccountType may have one of the following values: AccountsPayable,
         AccountsReceivable, CondenseItemAdjustmentExpenses, CostOfGoodsSold,
         DirectDepositLiabilities, Estimates, ExchangeGainLoss, InventoryAssets,
         ItemReceiptAccount, OpeningBalanceEquity, PayrollExpenses, PayrollLiabilities,
         PettyCash, PurchaseOrders, ReconciliationDifferences, RetainedEarnings,
         SalesOrders, SalesTaxPayable, UncategorizedExpenses, UncategorizedIncome,
         UndepositedFunds -->
      <SpecialAccountType >ENUMTYPE</SpecialAccountType> <!-- required -->
      <CurrencyRef> <!-- optional -->
        <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
        <FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
      </CurrencyRef>
    </SpecialAccountAdd>
    <IncludeRetElement >STRTYPE</IncludeRetElement> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
  </SpecialAccountAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The special accounts are account types that QuickBooks can create automatically. For example, if you don't have an Accounts Receivable account on your chart of accounts, and you try to create an invoice, QuickBooks will create an AR account called Accounts Receivable automatically. While it may be a special account, it still shows up in QuickBooks on your Chart of Accounts, just like regular accounts. There is not a separate UI for special accounts.